# Constant erroneous Outlook meeting reminders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

There was a recurring meeting that was set up in Outlook. The recurrences ended eighty weeks ago, but it still pops up with a meeting reminder saying that it's 80 weeks overdue, and it's been doing this for the full eighty weeks ever since. This pops up whenever I start Outlook, and also seems to show up in the reminder box every so often when some other legitimate meeting pops up a reminder. I can dismiss it just like anything else, but it strikes me as strange. This is Office 2007 against an Exchange 2003 server.

I remember doing some "flush" or "clear" command a while back, but it didn't seem to do the trick - my Google-fu on finding out exactly what I tried is failing me at the moment, though.

If I try to open the meeting in order to wipe it from my calendar, it just pops a warning dialog that says "Cannot open the item for this reminder," so my only option is just to dismiss it every time it comes up.

Any ideas how to make the phantom meeting reminder stop bugging me every day at work multiple times?

**EDIT:** BioXHazard found the command that I had run previously, "outlook /cleanreminders"...but the reminder still popped up on restart, so no dice there.

Comment: Are you syncing to any handheld device?  In the past, I've had issues when syncing my Palm where random reminders for really old events would come back.

Comment: @Adrien: Ah, good call. It used to sync to a Blackberry, but I haven't had it in about 10 months or so, so not sure if there are lingering issues with that. Hmm...

Comment: @chrisbro: are you in an Exchange environment?  Or, "what environment are you in" might be the better question.

Comment: It's Exchange 2003.

Comment: Have you tried running Auto Archive on the Calendar with "Delete Old Items" set?

Comment: That's a good idea...it looks like I can set it to "Delete Old Items" for the calendar folder, but I can only apply a certain folder's auto-archive properties when auto-archiving if I do my *entire* mailbox, so that'll have to wait until the end of the day as it always creates some strange behavior when I try to archive and use Outlook normally at the same time. Sounds promising, though.

Answer (score 1):

When the reminder comes up, click open. Then press the delete button at the top. The same was happening to me just today for the first time.

Comment: Yeah, gave that a shot when it first started, but it pops back an error saying "Cannot open the item for this reminder" so I can't take any further action :( ...it's like the meeting's corrupt.

Comment: Here, I found a fix where you can clear all the current reminders that are in the reminders box: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/windows/trbl_outlook_cnotiftr.htm

Comment: Aha, that was the "flush" command I couldn't remember from the original question. I gave it another shot, and no dice ...the reminder still pops up, very strange. Thanks for clarifying what that command was though, couldn't remember for the life of me.

Comment: Hmm, this is really weird. You tried restarting your computer already? Maybe reinstall Outlook (but you'll lost all the emails in there)

Comment: Actually, since he's using Exchange, he shouldn't lose anything.  Depending on where exactly the problem is coming from, it might work.

Comment: Interestingly, it's happened on two separate computers for the full eighty weeks now - so it doesn't seem localized to a single machine. I typically reboot once a week or so, doesn't seem to fix up anything.

Comment: It could possibly be an Outlook problem. Maybe we should notify them about it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not dismissing it but *snoozing* it for a stupidly long time like 999 weeks?

You can snooze a reminder for times not available in the drop-down list by typing them as long as you follow conventions - choose 2 weeks and edit that to 999 and see what happens

Comment: I tried this but I get `Cannot postpone the reminder. Sorry, something went wrong.  You may want to try again.`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar, however, this is for an ongoing recurring appointment. It shows me reminders from the start of the appointment.

I came across this article, installing a macro at start-up of Outlook to erase old appointment reminders: http://techniclee.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/killing-overdue-reminders-in-outlook/

I haven't installed it yet, but it looks like it could solve the issue presented here too.

Cheers,

Ron

Answer (score 0):

Had a Birthday reminder (== recurring event) coming up again and again since 2 weeks on every other new reminder in Outlook 2016.

In reminder window pressing "delete" key had just the effect that this single entry popped up in first line of other newer not dismissed lines again.
In calendar view of Outlook marking the birthday and pressing (w/ or w/o shift) "delete" key had no effect.
**Solution** for my case open "The entire series" in calendar view and using the "X" symbol to delete the series. This also wiped out the line in my still open reminder window. Drawback you might create the series from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Logon to Outlook online and delete the event from your calendar.

Source: ["FIX!!! You can't successfully dismiss calendar reminders in Outlook" (Youtube, see comment from Elyssa Figueira)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le9ST4Z8ikg)

Answer (score 0):

2022... and the problem still occurs. The only reliable solution is probably a different appointment calendar. Microsoft never seems to get Outlook right.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

2022 - this fixed it for me:
Open and sign into Outlook in the online version, not desktop:
https://outlook.office365.com/mail/

I could delete it from there, and now it is gone in my desktop app.